# Can level 30 actually be won?

Tags: immortal-defense

Talking about the last level of the 2nd arc, in Immortal Defence.
Excluding the Endless Assult. Title is "What the left hand did".

In this level there is just a single boss, plus a path defender combating you with there own towers.

I am wondering if you can actually win the level. Either by:

- Stalling the boss til the timer runs out.
- Or killing it outright.

I am starting to suspect that it is hard-coded so that no matter what you do you can never win. So that the math of the boss's stats ensure he always makes it to the end.

How this might happen (for clarity), would be if he can not actually be slowed down beyond a certain minimum speed -- and so is guaranteed to exit the level
after some maximum time, unless killed? And then him having enough health that no possible combination of towers on the level, can deal that much damage before he is certain to reach the end?

Alternitively, it may be flat impossible for his health to go below 20,000. It does look that way when I get him close to dead... Like the game is just changing his health back up.

If it can be beaten, what happens after?

> Note that even if you fail to defeat the boss and it remove's your last life, it still plays the "Won" dialogue and you can move forward in the game. For this reason, AFAICT the optimal strategy is to place no towers and let him win -- like Aa suggests.

Answer (score 3):

It is supposed to be impossible to beat the boss, but apparently it can be done.
So the game is meant to be coded to make it impossible to win, but never the less it can be done. This would be a "unintended feature" (i.e. a bug) in the game.

Beating it changes nothing in the game
I.e. it still displays that

> Your home world has been destroyed

This is [word from God (the games creator):](http://www.immortaldefense.com/faq)

> ARE YOU SUPPOSED TO LOSE ON THE SECOND BROTHER BAVAKH?
>   Yes. You *can* win, but you're not supposed to, and winning doesn't change the story or give you any special reward. I myself have never won, and I designed it so it couldn't be won, but apparently a few hardcore players managed to kill him anyhow.